# image doesn't display after getting the link from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I run a python script on my raspberry pi that takes a picture, moves it in the cloud and uploads the link to firebase.

Because the picture taking and uploading takes approximately 15 seconds I'm using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter.

In my current state, I'm able to take pictures whenever I want to, but there are 2 things I can't do.

1. How to be able to get the firebase element whenever a change happened. Python can do that, I don't know what the swift method for that.
2. The picture doesn't show. Is it because I want to display it from DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter?

Thanks

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class RpiOps: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ivImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var LblResult: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tvLink: UITextView!


    @IBAction func btn1Pic(_ sender: Any) {
        rpi2do(state: "single_pic")
        rpiResults(state: "-")

        let actityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        actityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        actityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        actityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        view.addSubview(actityIndicator)
        actityIndicator.startAnimating()

        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20) {
            actityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            //let post : [String: AnyObject] = ["2do": state as AnyObject]
            ref.child("rpi_results").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let ud = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
                let asa = ud["got"] as! String
                self.tvLink.text = asa
                print("asa:", asa)
                //self.LblResult

                let url = URL(string: asa)
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
                self.ivImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                self.displayAlert(title: "Finished!", message: "Your picture has been taken. See the link here: " + asa)

                //self.rpi2do(state: "-")
            })
        }
        rpi2do(state: "-")

    }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// rpi operation
func rpi2do(state: String) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let post : [String: AnyObject] = ["2do": state as AnyObject]
    ref.child("rpi2do").setValue(post)
}


// rpi operation
func rpiResults(state: String) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let post : [String: AnyObject] = ["got": state as AnyObject]
    ref.child("rpi_results").setValue(post)
}


func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write), I think you've got the right method above in observeSingleElement to answer your first question.   On the second one, make sure that you are getting the results of observeSingleEvent back onto the main thread before trying updating any UI elements, like below.  You may be seeing the no change in the photo because you are not on the main thread after the database call.

```
    ref.child("rpi_results").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let ud = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        let asa = ud["got"] as! String
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.tvLink.text = asa
            print("asa:", asa)
            //self.LblResult

            let url = URL(string: asa)
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
            self.ivImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            self.displayAlert(title: "Finished!", message: "Your picture has been taken. See the link here: " + asa)

            //self.rpi2do(state: "-")
        }
    })
```

Comment: I updated my code with yours but now it crashes. I inserted a couple of print statements and realized it crashes before the row DispatchQueue.main.sync { Nothing is written in the logcat regarding the error, only in the code: Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) Do you know what the solution is? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any more information from the crash than that?   did you check that ud["got"] and snapshot.value exist and are the correct type?  I'd set a breakpoint and step through what's happening.

Comment: My problem is that the ui shows up first and the firebase data retrievment is slower so after installing and opening the app (1st time) I cannot see the datas downloaded from firebase. BUT, when I go to a VC and get back to the menu ( I handle here fb datas) the datas have been refreshed and everything's fine. Do you see other solution than delaying the process so there is time for dowloading and processing data? Thanks

Comment: If the data is needed for visible UI elements on the very first view and you're getting that data from a potentially slow async call, there may not be much you can do other than wait for the data.   However you may be able to use a splash screen, UIActivityIndicatorView, or some animations to distract the user long enough for the data to load. Can you do something like collapsing or hiding the view area until the data is loaded (and possibly redesign the UI so the user wouldn't really notice/care)? There's always a chance the user's network will be bad too.  How are you handling that?